# How to implement inverting gradient in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying implement DDPG in Tensorflow. The action space is continuous with upper bound `P_max` and lower bound `P_min`. Based on [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/49da/57cf2900cd50d64a6d63d45e1bccd454fcbb.pdf), the inverting gradients is a good approach for continuous action space. However, I get stucked when update the actor network. I'll go through my code in the following.

First, I build placeholder for state, next_state, and reward. Where `S_DIM` is the state dimension.

```
self.S = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, S_DIM], name='state')
self.S_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, S_DIM], name='next_state')
self.R = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='reward')
```

Build neural network for actor and critic, where `A_DIM` is the action space:

```
def build_a(self, s, scope, trainable):
    with tf.variable_scope('actor'):
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(s, 100, tf.nn.relu,trainable=trainable)
            a = tf.layers.dense(l1, A_DIM, trainable=trainable)                
            return a

def build_c(self, s, a, scope, trainable):
    with tf.variable_scope('critic'):
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            concat_layer = tf.concat([s, a], axis=1)
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(concat_layer, 100, tf.nn.relu, trainable=trainable)
            q = tf.layers.dense(l1, 1, trainable=trainable)
            return q

self.a = self.build_a(self.S, scope='evaluation', trainable=True)
self.a_ = self.build_a(self.S_, scope='target', trainable=False)
self.q = self.build_c(self.S, self.a, scope='evaluation', trainable=True)
self.q_ = self.build_c(self.S_, a_, scope='target', trainable=False)
```

Access parameters in neural network for later use:

```
self.ae_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='actor/evaluation')
self.at_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='actor/target')
self.ce_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='critic/evaluation')
self.ct_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='critic/target')
```

Then, update critic with time-difference Bellman equation by minimizing the difference between `q_target` and `q`. `GAMMA` is the discount factor, for example: 0.99

```
q_target = self.R + GAMMA * q_
self.c_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(q_target, self.q_)
self.ctrain = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(self.c_loss, var_list=self.ce_params)
```

Finally, update actor (where I get stuck):

```
dq_da = tf.gradients(q, self.a)[0]  # partial Q, partial a
upper_method = lambda: dq_da * (upper - self.a) / (upper - lower)
lower_method = lambda: dq_da * (self.a - lower) / (upper - lower)
# if gradient suggests increasing action, apply upper method
# else, lower method
adjust_dq_da = tf.cond(tf.greater(dq_da, 0), upper_method, lower_method)
grad = tf.gradients(self.a, self.ae_params, grad_ys=adjust_dq_da)
# apply gradient to the parameters in actor network
self.atrain = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(-0.0001).apply_gradients(zip(grad, self.ae_params))
```

And I got error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'actor_gradient/cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,1], [?,1].
```

Is there any way to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve my question by create a placeholder for inverting gradients.

```
inverting_gradients_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1], name='inverting_gradeints')
```

First step, I compute the gradient of `Q` value w.r.t action `a`.

```
dq_da = tf.gradient(q, a)[0]
```

Second, I take gradient of action `a` w.r.t actor parameters `a_params`. Also define actor update operation.

```
grad = tf.gradients(a, a_params, grad_ys=inverting_gradients_placeholder)
train_actor = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate_actor).apply_gradients(zip(grad, a_params))
```

Finally, implement inverting gradients.

```
# get dq/da array, action array
dq_das, actions = sess.run([dq_da, a], feed_dict={state_placeholder: batch_state})
# inverting gradients, if dq_da >= 0, apply upper method, else lower method
inverting_gradients = []
for dq_da, action in zip(dq_das, actions):
    if dq_da >= 0.0:
        inverting_gradients.append(dq_da * (upper - action) / (upper - lower))
    else:
        inverting_gradients.append(dq_da * (action - lower) / (upper - lower))
inverting_gradients = np.array(inverting_gradients).reshape(-1, 1)
# update actor
sess.run(train_actor, feed_dict={state_placeholder: batch_state, inverting_gradients_placeholder: inverting_gradients})
```